# in Parallel.ForEach : The underlying provider failed on Open. with EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

This code would work sometimes for some items but it always fails when trying to process more items and I would get this : `{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}` exception

```
  List<Recon> scenarioAll = db.Transactions
                  .Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
                  .Select(t => t.Recon).ToList();


  //db.Transactions.Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13").ToList().ForEach(t => reconsWithType13Trans.Add(t.Recon));

  Parallel.ForEach(scenarioAll.Take(100), r =>
  {

    // ### Exception : {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} here ###
    invoices = r.Transactions.SelectMany(t => t.InvoiceDetails).ToList();


    CreateFacts(invoices, r/*, db*/).ForEach(f => facts.Add(f));
    transactions = r.Transactions.Where(t => !t.SrcObjTyp.Contains("13")).ToList();
    DistributeTransactionOnItemCode(transactions, facts);
    Console.WriteLine(i += 1);
  });

  facts.ForEach(f => db.ReconFacts.Add(f));
  db.SaveChanges();
```

I think the issus is multiple process accessing the database at the same time is it possible to allow EF to be queried by multiple process this way ?

Also is there a way to load everything in memory so when accessing the child of `Recon` like that `r.Transactions.SelectMany(t => t.InvoiceDetails).ToList();`everything would be in memory and not accessing the underlying database ?

What solution should I use what do you think is best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have multiple threads trying to Lazy load.
Try replacing  your load query with...

```
List<Recon> scenarioAll = db.Transactions
              .Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
              .Select(t => t.Recon)
              .Include(r => r.Transactions.Select(t => t.InvoiceDetails))
              .ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

Generally speaking if you are relying on Lazy Loading you are doing it wrong.

Alternatively, given that you might not need Transactions...you could do this...

```
 var query =  = db.Transactions
              .Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
              .Select(t => t.Recon);
 var scenarioAll = query.ToList();
 var invoicesByReconIdQuery = from r in query
                              from t in r.Transactions
                              from i in t.InvoiceDetails
                              group i by r.Id into g
                              select new { Id = g.Key, Invoices = g.ToList() };


 var invoicesByReconId = invoicesByReconIdQuery.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Invoices);

 Parallel.ForEach(scenarioAll.Take(100), r =>
 {

     // ### Exception : {"The underlying provider failed on Open."} here ###
     var invoices = invoicesByReconId[r.Id];
 }
```

Comment: Seems like a nice answer thank you. But now I get a "Timeout expired" exception ... Do you know how I can manage that ?

Comment: You can take a look at the generated SQL and try to add Indices to fix it. But at the end of the day, the dataset you will be bringing back is much larger. Try to figure out if it is a Bandwidth (unfixable) problem or a Latency problem (you can optimize the query).

Comment: PS your `.Take(100)` should be before the `.ToList()`...All you are doing now is taking the whole database out, then iterating over the first 100... You really want to ask the database for only 100 rows.

Comment: You are right for the take i figured it out and changed it. Thanks